# how do i make a small overlay at the bottom right corner with z-index 5?

Tags: css

i need a small overlay to display at the bottom right corner of the page

i can't get the position right

```
div#overlay {
z-index: 5;
float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
div#overlay { position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0; }
```

Something like this? z-index is *useless* without the element having a position of absolute/fixed/relative.

Comment: actually when i drag up and down, it disappears.

Comment: Are you looking to use `position:fixed` ?

Comment: Note that IE6 doesnt natively support it. You can use overflow-hidden on the `body` element and assign any position to the element for IE6 *only* or you can use a css expression. Would help seeing your desired result though.